# Spark SQL Performance optimisation

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am running a Spark SQL query with huge amount of data (approx 50 million records).Due to heavy records, Query becomes slower in the cluster, So that it was taking long time (20 mins) to process  the entire data. I am using inner join,left join inside the query.How can i improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are performing join operation and data size is huge, chances are lot of shuffling and I/O operation is involved. So if you are not using kryo serialization, your code would be using default Java Serialization. Use Kryo serialization, it gives better performance.
2. This one depends how you are storing your data in Hdfs. if its in a file format. Try creating Hive tables on top of it. Hive provides many optimisation technique.
   a. Partitiong and Bucketing : Partitioning speeds up query since you don't have to scan entire table while reading data. Bucketing speeds up join operation.

b. Map Side join can be used: Here smaller table is sent to memory where join operation is performed in mapper itself and thus speeding up query.

Apache Spark provides option to take benefit of Hive using Hive Context.